# Element go off screen while dragging~JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

```
function move(event){
    box.style.left=event.clientX-25+"px";
    box.style.top=event.clientY-25+"px";
}
```

I created a dynamically div element named box, and then added mouseup and mousedown events, In mouseup, mousemove event will be added, in mousedown , it will removed

when mousemove event will be added with the function move, and also removed with the same

I want to make sure that this element doesnot go off Screen while i am moving the mouse or dragging the box
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the dimensions of the dragged element beforehand, and then limit the the x and y based on the window's width&height:

```
var element_w = 50
var element_h = 50

function move(event){
    box.style.left=Math.max(0,Math.min(window.innerWidth-element_w,event.clientX-25))+"px";
    box.style.top=Math.max(0,Math.min(window.innerHeight-element_h,event.clientY-25))+"px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**mousemove** event gives the delta from the last **mousemove** event position.

With this information, you have two options:

1. Get the current position when the user first pressed the mouse button, and add it's delta to the initial values
2. Get the current position of the box on every mouse move and add the delta to it.

The second one is more memory consuming and will create a lag for the move because of the position calculations, so the first option is the one you should go with.

Don't want to interfere with your learning curve. But this is a common situation and wherever you search it, you'll find a correct and working answer. You just needed to search it. For example here is one: [javascript use drag to move element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831399/javascript-use-drag-to-move-element)